# SQL injection that bypasses website's firewall that filters table by its prefix

Tags: sql-injection

There is a website I am assessing for security breaches. It has Joomla 1.5.x with MySQL 5.5.24 and PHP 5.3.2.

I am doing a penetration test, that exploits SQL injection. The thing is that WAF filters many injections.  that have table name prefix: `...UNION SELECT * FROM **prefix__**tablename`?

Worked:

`.../*!UNION*/ SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns`

Didn't work or was filtered:

```
...UNION SELECT...`
.../*!UNION*/ UNION SELECT * FROM prefix_tablename`
.../*!UNION*/ UNION SELECT * FROM prefi/**/x_tablename`
```

Comment: Can you access the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`?

Comment: @Matthew, yes, I can get the list of table names and table columns. But I cannot access themselves, because firewall filters all requests with them.

Comment: What exactly does the WAF filter? Just the `prefix__` part? The full `UNION SELECT...` query fragment?

Comment: @Anders, WAF filters also UNION, but I was able to mitigate it with /*!UNION*/ expression. What I cannot bypass is whenever I execute a SELECT FROM that mentions any table that starts with Joomla DB prefix (e.g. jos_), it returns  `403: Access Forbidden` and `Attempted SQL injection in REQUEST_URI`

Comment: Do you have access to the firewall rules? If so, post them. If not, post a list of things that does pass and things that doesn't pass. Having that will make it much more easier to guess what is going on.

Comment: Can you alias the table reference?  Otherwise, the standard suspects apply - creating views over the table, if you can do multiple/delimited statements.  Using encoded Unicode code points instead of character literals, and/or control characters (like backspace) to otherwise modify the text.  That, or just do things the "long way", and `OR 1=1` if you have a statement giving you interesting columns.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse, I cannot mention these tables in any way. Aliasing the table reference would also mention the table in my request, which is turned down by firewall (simply done by this prefix). Maybe you know some way of escaping table name or underscore symbol?

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR, no.

If the WAF is configured correctly and doing its job, you have no way of injecting that info. Javascript allows variation of "script" for XSS etc `onclick=alert(XSS pwn'd!)` instead of `<script>alert(pwn'd!)</script>` etc), but SQL does not. SQL injections are, by and large, very fickle and require very precise queries with very precise order. If the WAF is blocking union or select, you're probably dead in the water. You might be able to find a fancy way around it, but unless the client is paying big bucks and you're ready to spend a week on it, it's probably best to move on to another vulnerability.

It's unfortunate - I've done many penetration tests where compensating controls are used in place of secure coding. However, frustrations and bad practice aside, it is what it is.

PLEASE NOTE this doesn't mean joomla, PHP and whatever else doesn't have *other* vulnerabilities that can be exploited. Exploit-db.com is your friend here. `Joomla 1.5` has 86 results in exploit-db.com, and PHP 5 has undoubtedly hundreds if not thousands. Please remember: penetration testing and vulnerability scanning is all about ENUMERATION!